# PayPal Integration

Tags: php, paypal

I have a website which will be added paypal integration. But i still not sure which method (paypal merchant service) is right for me.

My website is selling service like placing banner in my website, which i want it automate published when the customer already paid through paypal. THe flow is like this.

1. Customer input form and information where to place the image.
2. From admin panel, then i will be select to approve or not this banner.
3. if i choose approve. My script will create temporary data which this banner is already approved and on the other hand my script will also contact the paypal to create invoice and send it to the customer.
4. After the customer get the mail from paypal, if the customer is already paid. Then i will receive information about this through mail. and paypal also contact me (contact atomically via Program Script, in this case is PHP) which give me infortaion the banner for ID (identification number) is paid. Then my script will set this banner to published.
5. Me and Customer get notification if the banner is published.

Can somebody inform me which paypal service can do that?

Thank you for your help,
GusDe

Comment: @dagon: sorry i didn't understand what you mean?

Comment: website payments standard\pro will both work for this. you should read there docs for the differences https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/compare_wp_products

Comment: @dagon: okay i will test payment stanrd for now, since i want the customer to pay from PayPal website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why do you want to approve the banners - I think its rather a small possibility that your users will want to pay for advertising and display spammy banners. I would go with a simplified process - implement a 'shopping cart' for the banners - location, size, exposure time, etc - let the user choose what he wants and needs, compute a sum to be paid and then direct the user straight to the PayPal to let him pay, automatically approving the banner appearance. If you make the user wait between his order and your approval, there are very big chances that the customer will change his mind and not buy anymore.

Anyway, both workflows can be implemented using PayPal's [Instant Payment Notification](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro)

Comment: why i need approve first is, i didn't want my customer put pornography banner or SARA banner.

Comment: You can specify that in your Terms of service, stating that if adult or SARA banners found, they will be banned, without refunds

Comment: yes maybe we can use that. but my website is viewed by much visitor. if the banner already published and its a porn. there will be much visitor view it and make my website look not professional.

Comment: Worst case scenario - a porn banner is submitted and it will start displaying immediately - if you have mail alerts on your phone, that banner will be displayed for maximum 10-20 minutes - and you will cash pretty much money - small 'damage' for big income - I would take the risk - although, I don't think any porn promoters would risk their money

Comment: sometime we need to follow our customer scenario :)